# Why does simple commerce module not update member group upon successful completion of the transaction?

Tags: ecommerce, paypal, simple-commerce

We've setup the simple commerce module in Exp Eng v2.7.2 - Build Date: 20131008 and I've successfully purchased some subscription items through PayPal using live, actual transactions. Everything seems to be working okay except that the Member Group in Exp Eng is not being changed upon purchase as was intended. Notification emails go out and the transaction shows up on my own PayPal account as "Unclaimed".

Is it necessary to wait until the transaction is fully completed before the Member Group is updated? Will we have to do the member group change manually? Is there something off with my IPN setup? How do you view IPN responses in the Exp Eng control panel (or elsewhere)?

Thanks.

Comment: I have just run across this, I am curious if you found a fix?

From my testing unless you select the "Recurring" option in the item setup it will not move user groups for the purchase. Ticking this box (which pays as a paypal subscription, and not a one time payment, functions as intended. However in my use case, the client does NOT want a paypal subscription, but instead a one time payment.

Comment: The PayPal account we were using was not yet 'verified' in the PayPal setup so I assumed the IPN responses were not being returned and the member group was not being changed because of that. But it is more likely as you describe, that the 'product' was not setup as a recurring purchase. The PayPal account is now verified but we are considering moving to the 'Charge' Exp Eng add-on that uses Stripe as the payment gateway. Our need is for a subscription service and most of the e-commerce packages,CartThrob, Brilliant, say they don't really support a subscription model. Charge seems made for that

Comment: Thanks for the response, I too would like to use charge but my client really wants Paypal, so i cannot. :(